# What settings are being edited behind the scenes in Universal Access?

Tags: keyboard, accessibility

I was looking at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/460632/make-altd-act-like-alttab-hud). I know there is a setting within Universal Access which allows keystrokes to have a delay between I/O.

I am wondering what is actually being edited behind the scenes (config files). Is it within X, or somewhere else?